# C# fast loseless image rotation

Tags: c#, image, rotation

I need to rotate an image by 90, 180 and 270 degrees. For 180 degree rotation can be used simple `RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone)`, but for 90 and 270 i can't find a suitable algorithm.

Various algorithms like

```
public Image RotateImage(Image img)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(img);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gfx.Clear(Color.White);
        gfx.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
    }

    bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    return bmp;
}
```

seems to be lowering the image quality during resize.

I tried to make it head-on like

```
result = new Bitmap(source, new Size(source.Height, source.Width));
for (int i = 0; i < source.Height; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < source.Width; j++)
        result.SetPixel(i, j, source.GetPixel(j, source.Height - i - 1));
```

but it takes about 20 seconds to rotate an 3600x2400 image.

How can I rotate an image without lowering its quality and fast at the same time?

Why do my algorithm is so inefficient?

**UPD:**

Trying to make this code work:

```
result = new Bitmap(source.Height, source.Width, source.PixelFormat);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
{
    g.TranslateTransform((float)source.Width / 2, (float)source.Height / 2);
    g.RotateTransform(90);
    g.TranslateTransform(-(float)source.Width / 2, -(float)source.Height / 2);
    g.DrawImage(source, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: Getting and setting pixels is quite slow and WinForms is not hardware accelerated.  If the intent is merely to display the image in a different orientation, use a transform rather than alter the underlying raster.  See **neiiic**'s answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Rotate with Graphics gfx. If you use `RotateFlip` you have a lot of extra effort.
For image transformations use graphics not image. Its faster and more effective.
Graphics are very powerful and allow you to do image manipulation really easily.

```
gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
```

Comment: Can you provide some hints or code? I am trying to write a function using `RotateTransform` (added sample code to the question) but still can't.

Comment: @AndrewR What problem you have here?

Comment: I can't figure out how to use `RotateFlip` properly. Found this example, but it returns a messed up image. Without `TranslateTransform` it returns blank image.

Comment: Angle must be a float. Like 90.f .

Comment: Here is definition of Bitmap: `public Bitmap(int width,int height,PixelFormat format)`. Change `result = new Bitmap(source.Height, source.Width, source.PixelFormat);` to `result = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, source.PixelFormat);`

Comment: No, it still looks like the corner of an image on a white background. But I've found another way so it's not actual for me anymore. But thanks for help)